# Updating Repeated Array Struct BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have (apparently with 104559 rows affected) successfully updated an element of my session_user repeated field (within the table definition see below) with:

```
UPDATE genderfitnessdev.gfa_talend_dev.gfa_employment_cu
set session_user = ARRAY (
                      SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE('399975' as level_0)
                      FROM UNNEST(session_user)
                      )
where true
```

Then I select from the table:

```
select * from `genderfitnessdev.gfa_talend_dev.gfa_employment_cu`
```

With the following results (session_user is not populated):??

```
[
  {
"Emplid": "386957",
"Code": "HR",
"Name_display": "Andrea",
"First_name": "Andrea",
"Last_name": "xxxx",
"EMPL_Status": "T",
"Sex": "F",
"Company": "BET",
"Hire_dt": "2014-05-05",
"Termination_dt": "2015-05-15",
"Tree_node": "BETFAIR",
"allowed_viewer": null,
"allowed_group": null,
"session_user": []
  },
  {
"Emplid": "028308",
"Code": "JJ",
"Name_display": "Trudy",
"First_name": "Trudy",
"Last_name": "xxxxx",
"EMPL_Status": "T",
"Sex": "F",
"Company": "CC",
"Hire_dt": "2002-04-08",
"Termination_dt": "2002-08-10",
"Tree_node": "CROWN F&B",
"allowed_viewer": null,
"allowed_group": null,
"session_user": []
  },
.
.
.
.
```

Table Definition:

```
"schema": {
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "Emplid",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Code",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name_display",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "First_name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Last_name",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "EMPL_Status",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sex",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Company",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hire_dt",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Termination_dt",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tree_node",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "allowed_viewer",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "allowed_group",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_0",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_1",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_2",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_3",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_4",
     "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_5",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_6",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_7",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_8",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_9",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "level_10",
        "type": "STRING"
     }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "session_user",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
]
   }
```

Is the issue with the UPDATE or the SELECT as I would expect to see at least session_user.level_0 populated with the string??

Comment: How do you know that the arrays were not empty initially?

Comment: i just tested  - and your syntax is correct and works perfectly. meantime if row has empty array for session_user field it obviously leaves it empty as nothing to update.

Comment: I have also conducted a quick test using your syntax and got to the same conclussion as Mikhail. Note that even rows with empty arrays count towards the number of affected rows.

Comment: Thanks all - yes the arrays were empty initially (added the column to an existing table). So am I correct in saying that I need to populate the array with initial values? If so, would this be via an INSERT statement? Thanks:)

Comment: You can either use an update or recreate the table having the original data carry valid initial values.

Comment: Thanks Mar Cial - do you have an example of the syntax to initially populate the array with default values (say zero)? An INSERT?? Then I can rerun my update - and check if I can see the values:)

Comment: see the answer I proposed

Answer (score 0):

Given your latest comments, all you've done is adding a new REPEATED RECORD column "session_user". In such a case, it will have empty arrays for all rows and, for this reason, the UPDATE construct used does not really affect those "104559 rows affected".

If I have understood correctly, and none of your rows contains valid values on session_user, then you can use the following syntax to insert some dummy values:

```
UPDATE `genderfitnessdev.gfa_talend_dev.gfa_employment_cu`set session_user = ARRAY<STRUCT<level_0 string, level_1 string,level_2 string,level_3 string,level_4 string,level_5 string,level_6 string,level_7 string,level_8 string,level_9 string,level_10 string>>
  [('level_0', 'level_1','level_2','level_3','level_4','level_5','level_6','level_7','level_8','level_9','level_10')] where true
```